# Oracle SQL Alter Table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have two tables as below

```
CREATE TABLE "CLIENT" 
("ID" NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"FIRSTNAME" VARCHAR2(255 CHAR), 
"LASTNAME" VARCHAR2(255 CHAR), 
"TELEPHONE" VARCHAR2(255 CHAR), 
CONSTRAINT "CLIENT_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID"))

CREATE TABLE "BCR"."RESERVATION" 
("ID" NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"MYDATE" DATE,  
"USERS_ID" NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"CLIENT_ID" NUMBER(*,0), 
CONSTRAINT "RESERVATION_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID"),
CONSTRAINT "RESERVATION_USER_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("USERS_ID")
REFERENCES "USERS" ("ID"))
```

I need to modify the table by using this code (I want add ON DELETE CASCADE)

```
ALTER TABLE "RESERVATION"
ADD CONSTRAINT "RESERVATION_CLIENT_FK" 
FOREIGN KEY ("CLIENT_ID")
REFERENCES "CLIENT" CONSTRAINT "CLIENT_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

However, getting this error

```
SQL Error: ORA-01735: invalid ALTER TABLE option
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

try this code

```
ALTER TABLE "RESERVATION"
ADD CONSTRAINT "RESERVATION_CLIENT_FK" 
FOREIGN KEY ("CLIENT_ID")
REFERENCES "CLIENT" ("ID")
ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Here is the link to Oracle's documentation on [constraint](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/clauses002.htm#SQLRF52180) for reference